# Cannot get JSON data as text from a url in jquery for phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using this code to get the data as text from a SOAP web service like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn").click(  function () {
        alert("s");
          $.ajax({
              url: 'http://magicmap.skmm.gov.my/McmcServicemain_bb.asmx/Login?UserName=navdeep@gmail.com&Password=abc',
              dataType: "text",
              async: true,
              success: function (result) {
                  alert(result);
              },
              error: function (request,error) {
                  alert('Network error has occurred please try again!'+request +error);
              }
          });    

    });
});
```

Here if I change the URL and use the same JSON using [JSON GENERATOR](http://www.json-generator.com/j/cegsbDoJsO?indent=4) then it works well and return the data perfectly.

Is there any difference in these two URL please help me I am stuck here from 2 days . I am new to JQuery . Thanks

Comment: remove string tag in this file http://magicmap.skmm.gov.my/McmcServicemain_bb.asmx/Login?UserName=navdeep@gmail.com&Password=abc and add in your $.ajax function dataType: "json" use this in success function var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `json-generator.com` URL works because it supports [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). It sets the response header:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

This means that you can make cross domain requests. Your other URL doesn't output the CORS header and so the browser rejects the response.

To get your other URL to work, you'll have to proxy the request through a server side script on the same domain because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: How can I proxy the request ?